# PHP doesn't get AJAX JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Trying to get json array from ajax, but when i'm trying to write it down in the text file, it shows nothing.

```
 var img = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("iPath"));
                var img = JSON.stringify(img);
                console.log(img);

                $.ajax({
                    url: './php/temporary.php?deletefile',
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: img,
                    success: function( respond, textStatus, jqXHR ){

                        if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
                            //window.location.assign("/buyplace.html");
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log('ОШИБКИ ОТВЕТА сервера: ' +  respond.error );
                        }
                    },
                    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                        console.log('ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: ' + textStatus );
                    }
                });

 if( isset( $_GET['deletefile'] ) ){
        $params = json_decode( $_POST);
        $myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, $params);
        //$img = "uploads/" . $imgPath;
        //move_uploaded_file($imgPath, "./uploads/");
        //unlink('./uploads/' . $img);
    }
    ?>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: In your ajax call it is type of POST and the php is looking for the GET of it
change the php to
    if( isset($_POST[''deletefile])){}.   Also deletefile in your ajax call is going to be empty and not set  also try changing the .php?deletefile=true

Comment: You may need to use `$jsondata = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))`

Comment: well... `$_GET['deletefile']` is on the URL line, so it should still be populated.

Comment: `$_GET['deletefile']` is fine, it is the data that is not being accessed correctly.

Comment: What does `img` contain?

Comment: @Barmar {"name":"2313_12.png","path":"/tmp/phpNu1mXb"}

Comment: Why are you sending it as JSON? Just send the object, then you can use `$_POST['name']` and `$_POST['path']` in PHP.

Comment: @Barmar how can i do it? var img = localStorage.getItem("iPath"); I guess doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST` will contain key-value pairs and what you are sending, is a string.

So you should either read the standard input, or you need to make sure that you are actually sending key-value pairs.

The first case is already posted as a comment by @Scuzzy.

For the latter, using the standard key-value pairs in `$_POST`:

```
 $.ajax({
      url: './php/temporary.php?deletefile',
      cache: false,
      type: 'POST',
      data: {json: img},
      // the rest of your js
```

And in php:

```
if( isset( $_GET['deletefile'] ) ){
    $params = json_decode($_POST['json']);
    // the rest of your php
```

Comment: still nothing in the file

Comment: @VitoMotorsport There is a lot that is supposed to be happening between you calling your javascript and php writing the file. You need to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to send the parameters as JSON. You can use an object as the `data:` option, and each property will be sent as the corresponding `$_POST` element.

```
var img = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("iPath"));
console.log(img);

$.ajax({
    url: './php/temporary.php?deletefile',
    cache: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: img,
    success: function( respond, textStatus, jqXHR ){
        if( typeof respond.error === 'undefined' ){
            //window.location.assign("/buyplace.html");
        }
        else{
            console.log('ОШИБКИ ОТВЕТА сервера: ' +  respond.error );
        }
    },
    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        console.log('ОШИБКИ AJAX запроса: ' + textStatus );
    }
});
```

In PHP, you'll need to use `json_encode()` to convert the `$_POST` array to a string that can be written to a file.

```
if( isset( $_GET['deletefile'] ) ){
    $params = $_POST;
    $myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
    fwrite($myfile, json_encode($params));
}
```